# Kriege auslösen / Kriege verursachen

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Bedeutungunterschied zwischen den beiden Verben "auslösen" und "verursachen", wenn es um Kriege geht?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vorausgeschickt: Ich habe eine Problem mit den beiden Verben "auslösen" und "verursachen" für Kriege. Beide stellen eine Situation vor, als werde ein Krieg 'ausgelöst' wie ein Erdrutsch oder sonstiges Naturereignis. Dabei fällt unter den Tisch, dass Kriege immer von sehr konkreten Akteuren **begonnen, angezettelt, erklärt, geführt** [...] werden. Kurz, ich könnte mir kaum eine Situation vorstellen, in der man (in gutem, gedankenvollem) Deutsch die beiden Verben zusammen mit 'Krieg' wirklich verwenden könnte. Ich würde immer versuchen, zu erwähnen, **wer** den Krieg nun **angefangen** hat. Ich gebe zu, dass das vielleicht nicht immer so einfach ist...

Diese Bedenken hintanstellend mag man vielleicht historisch darüber nachdenken, ob der Erste Weltkrieg durch das Attentat auf den Habsburger Thronfolger Franz Ferdinand in Sarajevo *ausgelöst* wurde. In manchen Kurzdarstellungen mag das so zu finden sein. Richtig gut formuliert finde ich es aber nicht. Und *verursacht* kann man hier um so weniger sagen, denn das Attentat war wenn schon dann wirklich nur ein *Auslöser* und nicht etwa die *Ursache* - diese wird man (nach vorherrschender Lesart) in vielerlei nationalen Befindlichkeiten sowie internationalen Vertragskonstrukten der Zeit suchen (oder auch in ökonomischem Verhältnissen, wenn man marxistisch argumentieren möchte).

Antwort somit: Ja, es gibt einen Unterschied zwischen

> einen Krieg auslösen

(das wäre: vordergründig in der Ereigniskette stehen)

> einen Krieg verursachen

(das wäre: das Kernelement der Ereigniskette sein).

Comment: Weder *verursachen*, noch *auslösen* werden ausschließlich für Naturereignisse benutzt. Bei Kriegen gibt es generell meist 2 oder mehr Ansichten über deren Entstehung. Keine der aufgelisteten Alternativen (beginnen, anzetteln, erklären, führen) eignet sich als Ersatz für eines der beiden Wörter. "Ich würde immer versuchen, zu erwähnen, wer den Krieg nun angefangen hat." ist eine Aussage, die unterstellt, dass es jemanden gibt, der den Krieg angefangen hat, dass man weiß wer, und es keine anderen, dominierenden Interessen gibt die Erwähnung zu unterlassen, was reichlich praxisfern ist. Abs. 2f+

Comment: "als werde ein Krieg 'ausgelöst' wie ein Erdrutsch oder sonstiges Naturereignis" - ohne zur einen oder anderen Position Stellung zu beziehen, musste ich bei dieser Antwort unwillkürlich an eine kürzlich gelesene Antwort von [politics.se] denken: ["In Japan meanwhile war is seen like some sort of natural disaster that causes great harm, like an earthquake or a tsunami. (...) hoping war will not return. No-one seems to be blamed for the war, its causes are somehow abstract and unimportant."](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/1282/7554).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Interessant. Hier im "Westen" versuchen wir ja eher, zu verstehen, wie die Dinge passiert sind, und da kommt man bei Kriegen doch immer wieder auf menschliche Akteure.

Answer (score 1):

Zwischen *»einen Krieg **auslösen**«* und *»... **verursachen**«* sehe ich keinen wesentlichen Bedeutungsunterschied. Zwei Beispiele fallen mir ein.

**Beispiel 1:** Die Luftüberwachung meldet eine anfliegende Rakete, wo keine ist. Es kommt zu einem »Vergeltungsschlag« und danach zu einem Krieg.

Hier lässt sich sagen:

> Ein technischer Defekt hat einen Krieg ausgelöst / verursacht.

**Beispiel 2:** Der Geheimdienst will zwei benachbarte Staaten destabilisieren. Nachts schleicht sich ein Kommando in Staat 1 und schießt von dort Raketen auf Staat 2. Hierauf beschießt Staat 2 Staat 1 und es kommt zum Krieg.

Hier lässt sich sagen:

> Der Geheimdienst hat einen Krieg ausgelöst / verursacht.

Noch besser passt hier aber ein anderes Verb:

> Der Geheimdienst hat einen Krieg provoziert.

Comment: Ja, in deinen Beispielen kann man beide Verben verwenden, ohne dann groß drüber zu stolpern. Aber im Franz-Ferdinand-Beispiel (siehe meine Antwort) geht das schlecht. Der Satz "Das Attentat in Sarajevo hat den Ersten Weltkrieg verursacht" funktioniert nicht richtig.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Dass beide Verben immer gleich gut in den Satz passen, habe ich auch nicht gesagt, in deinem wie auch in meinen Beispielen würde ich _»auslösen«_ jeweils bevorzugen. Selbst bei deinem Beispiel ist aber auch _»verursachen«_ inhaltlich nicht falsch, weil der 1. Weltkrieg ohne besagtes Attentat womöglich gar nicht stattgefunden hätte, selbiges war innerhalb der Kausalkette die finale Ursache.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, **verursachen** und **auslösen** sind nicht das Gleiche.

**Verursachen** bedeutet, dass eine Handlung eine bestimmte Konsequenz nach sich zieht. 
Beispiel:

> Wenn ich im Straßenverkehr nicht auf die Ampel achte, **verursache** ich
>   damit einen Unfall.

Meine Unachtsamkeit kann hier also zweifellos als Ursache für den Unfall zugeordnet werden.

Im Gegensatz dazu ist das Kind, welches die Straße korrekt mit Hilfe der Ampel überquert hat, nicht die Ursache für den Unfall (weil es sich korrekt verhalten hat).

Wäre das Kind aber nicht da gewesen, hätte es trotz meiner Unachtsamkeit keinen Unfall gegeben. Daher hat das Kind den Unfall **ausgelöst**, aber nicht 
**verursacht**.

Hier ist noch ein anderes Beispiel:

> Der Tropfen (Auslöser) hat die Badewanne überlaufen lassen. Der hohe Wasserstand
>   wurde aber durch den verstopften Abfluss **verursacht**.

Und ein Beispiel, welches sich auf den Krieg bezieht:

> Der Bauer aus Königreich A weigerte sich sein preisgekröntes Pferd dem
>   Herzog aus Königreich B zu schenken und **löste** damit einen Krieg
>   zwischen A und B **aus**, welcher durch die andauernden
>   Feindseligkeiten zwischen König A und B **verursacht** wurde.

Die Weigerung des Bauern hätte in friedlichen Zeiten zu keinem Krieg geführt. Er hat ihn daher nicht verursacht.

Die beiden Könige dagegen waren so zerstritten, dass sie auch über einem anderen Anlass in den Krieg gezogen wären. Sie waren die Ursache.